Instant noodle flavour/ flavor enhancers – beyond mere MSG
Instant noodles typically contain three flavour enhancers: the infamous MSG (typically at 97%), and the much more expensive disodium inosinate at 1.5% and disodium guanlytate also at 1.5% to make up the century.  Taken together these make up a "super salt", something that keeps us hungry for processed food.  But it doesn't have to be this way.  A high-sodium diet should be able to coincide as much with broccoli as pre-fried ramen.  After years of on-and-off searching, I at last dangle my saltiest parts into this cauldron of opinions and expert knowledge: whence can consumers acquire these rare salts?  Can they be synthesised out of baking soda or angry tears?  Hungrily yours, in moutwatering anticipation of your vastly superior knowledge of the connections between Nissin and boiled carrots.

There's nothing wrong with MSG, it's naturally occurring in soy products, ketchup, mushrooms and more.

It might not be disodium inosinate, but inosinic acid is in a lot of fermented and dried seafood products (fish sauce, oyster sauce, bonito flakes, etc). You might also look for ‘instant fashion powder’ if you have a store that sells Japanese stuff.

You have a typo in the tag name "guanylate".

@GdD – I am of the school that agrees.

@jogloran – thank you for spotting "gwan-lye-tate" – that is shameful, and I wholeheartedly apologise to all mystified or mislead.

Wikipedia says they're made through fermentation.  You can find DI/DG mixes on Amazon.  Ajinomoto sells 1-kg packs (~1000 servings) of MSG/DI/DG for food service use. If you get friendly with an Asian restaurant, maybe they'll resell you a bag.
